# Flattening of JSON for analysis

Tags: python, json, pandas

Require a small help. I need to flatten this json so that i can use it for analysis.

Sample for the json is :

```
{'data': [{'tag': 'U128_CRC_2', 'timestamp': 1575234889002, 'value': 0.0}],
 'metadata': {'event': 'alarm.reset',
  'idx': '1372',
  'timestamp': 1575234889.002701},
 'productID': '41ae4b41-56be-4bf2-a6a8-7aee4d15bf54',
 'timestamp': 1575234889008,
 'topicIdx': '1'}
```

I ran the following code :

```
from pandas import json_normalize

with open('NewJson.json') as f:
    d1 = json.load(f)

works_data = json_normalize(data=d1, record_path='data', 
                            meta=['tag','value','timestamp'])
```

I get the below error for the same:

```
KeyError: "Try running with errors='ignore' as key 'tag' is not always present"
```

Can anybody please help

Comment: Did you try the error message's suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the 'data' key is a list **and** a dictionary. You have to remove the list manually:

Example:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
d1 = {'data': [{'tag': 'U128_CRC_2', 'timestamp': 1575234889002, 'value': 0.0}],
 'metadata': {'event': 'alarm.reset',
  'idx': '1372',
  'timestamp': 1575234889.002701},
 'productID': '41ae4b41-56be-4bf2-a6a8-7aee4d15bf54',
 'timestamp': 1575234889008,
 'topicIdx': '1'}

d1['data'] = d1.get('data')[0]

works_data = json_normalize(data=d1)
works_data
```

Output:

```
            productID                               timestamp       topicIdx    data.tag        data.timestamp  data.value     metadata.event   metadata.idx    metadata.timestamp
0           41ae4b41-56be-4bf2-a6a8-7aee4d15bf54    1575234889008   1           U128_CRC_2      1575234889002   0.0            alarm.reset      1372            1.575235e+09
```